# Site API and connection to the server

Tags: c++, api, server

I want to try to create my first project in C++, an idea has arisen in my head, but I just don't understand how this can be implemented.

What do I want to do?

There is a site https://vk.com/dev/callback_api which describes the various callback API methods that the site itself can send to my web server. At this stage, a question arises. How can I implement the reception of these callback methods so that after they are sent to my server, it can also send the necessary data to the user on the computer so that he can read them and somehow interact with them?

In some places I used a translator, because I'm not particularly strong in English. I will be glad to see answer

Comment: c++ is probably a bit too complicated to build a web server unless you have some skills already. I would suggest to build a simple web server using javascript/typescript running on node.js, or a python web server running flask or django.  using these frameworks you can start with just a few lines of code as oposed to mastering c++. not that it cannot be done, it is just much more complicated and also much more easy to introduce security flaws. see: [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) or [node web server](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the question is still the same. How can I send a request from the server, for example using Python Django, to the user's computer?

Comment: Your server, that will be called from the VK api, will also act as a server for the users computer, which will create and maintain a websocket connection to your server. Websockets is a mechanism that allows servers, to send notifications to connected clients.

Comment: The server doesn't send requests to the client. The client sends requests to your server. The server sends a request (as a client) to the API. The API responses to your server. Your server sends a response to the client. This is the most simple synchronous way. The asynchronous way can be implemented through short polling, long polling or web sockets.

Comment: Do you have any experience with HTTP communication?

Comment: Perhaps I expressed my thought a little differently, so I will repeat myself. There is a web site that has a callback API (when a certain event is triggered, this site can send a JSON request to my web server). I want to know how I can send the same request, but to users' computers who should see this same JSON file, using a program written in C ++?